# Как сверстать полоску с наcечками?

Tags: html, css, css3

Вот есть такой макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.loader {
  height: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeedfd;
  background: #eeedfd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

.loader_line {
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(134.45deg, #7065F8 0%, #9B93FC 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(134.45deg, #7065F8 0%, #9B93FC 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader_line" style="right:calc(100% - 85% )"></div>
</div>
```

То есть есть серый фон и синий, но нет полупрозрачных боковых насечек? Как их сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --color-one: #8B86F1;
  --color-two: #7B76F1;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 400px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
  background: linear-gradient( 225deg, var(--color-one) 25%, var(--color-two) 25%, var(--color-two) 50%, var(--color-one) 50%, var(--color-one) 75%, #008283 75%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

> Блок класса loading-container только задает расположение и центрует
> полосу загрузки.

```
<div class="loading-container">
    <div class="loading-bar">
        <div class="amount green" style="width: 40%;"> <!-- The width (and colour in class) -->
            <div class="loaded">
                40% <!-- Loaded amount -->
            </div>
            <div class="lines"></div> <!-- The lines! -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Для начала зададим стили блоку класса **loading-container**. Всего
> несколько свойств, чтобы *отцентровать* полосу загрузки.

```
.loading-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.loading-container .loading-bar {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

> После этого зададим стили блокам класса **loading-bar** и **amount**. Блок
> класса **loading-bar** будет *фиксированной ширины*, а размер блока класса
> **amount** будет *процентом* от родительского блока. Потом можно менять
> *ширину* блока класса amount, чтобы она соответствовала этапам загрузки.

```
.loading-bar {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 61px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #282f32;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.amount {
    /* we haven't included the colour yet, we'll get to that later. */
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

> Затем давайте рассмотрим класс lines, задающий фон. Самое интересное в
> нем то, что как фон используется элемент **SVG**. Мы создадим файл **SVG**
> после того, как закончим задавать стили **CSS**. Еще зададим все анимации
> этому классу, что будет рассмотрено *чуть позже*. Если браузер не
> поддерживает анимации, полоса загрузки *будет статичной*, что не так уж
> плохо.

```
.lines {
    /* the lines overflow the container. This creates a continuous flow of the background */
    width: 200%;
    /* We use a SVG file as the background */
    background: url('lines.svg') repeat-x;
    height: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -35px;
    /* Any overflow is hidden */
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50px;
    /* Implement the animations, we'll get to that later */
    -webkit-animation: moveBars 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveBars 1s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: moveBars 1s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveBars 1s linear infinite;
    animation: moveBars 1s linear infinite;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    color: 1px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

> Следующий класс создан только для того, чтобы *задать стили тексту*
> поверх полосы загрузки.
>
> После этого наконец-то переходим к цветам. Просто добавьте какие
> хотите тени блока и цвета фона.

```
.loaded {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    top: 9px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.green {
    background-color: #8ac320;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 0 10px 10px -5px #79aa1e , 0 7px 0 #628c14;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #20b9c3;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 0 10px 10px -5px #1e8aaa, 0 7px 0 #13768c;
}
.red {
    background-color: #dc6565;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 0 10px 10px -5px #d23333, 0 7px 0 #8c1212;
}
```

> И, наконец, анимации. Все, что нам нужно — сдвинуть блок класса lines
> на 180px влево. Так что на **100** процентах, т. е., в конце анимации,
> изменим левый внешний отступ на **-180px**. Обычно анимации занимают много
> места в файле **CSS** из-за приставок производителей, но тут все
> уместилось в *5* строк:

```
/* ANIMATIONS */
@keyframes moveBars { 100% { margin-left: -180px; } }
@-webkit-keyframes moveBars { 100% { margin-left: -180px; } }
@-moz-keyframes moveBars { 100% { margin-left: -180px; } }
@-ms-keyframes moveBars { 100% { margin-left: -180px; } }
@-o-keyframes moveBars { 100% { margin-left: -180px; } }
```

> И это все, что касается кода **CSS**.
>
> Теперь перейдем к фону, состоящему из файла **SVG**.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="180" height="180">
  <title>Diagonal Lines</title>
  <desc>Some diagonal lines for use in the loading bar.</desc>
 <polygon fill="white" opacity="0.2" points="90,0 180,0 90,180 0,180" />
</svg>
```

> Что означает эта запись? Первая строка — как тип документа для
> документов **HTML**. После этого задаем для **SVG** название и описания, для
> правильной и понятной структуры. Затем  рисуем полигон. Это просто
> белая форма с прозрачностью **0.2**. После чего задаем точки. Это
> координаты в документе, по котором мы хотим расположить полигоны.
> Каждый набор точек отделен пробелом. После всего этого Вам остается
> только поместить этот код в файл с названием *lines.svg*  и сохранить
> его в той же категории, что и Ваш файл **CSS**.

[image: Итоговый результат]

[Источник](https://www.dejurka.ru/css/css-animated-loading-bars/)